# How to use Amazon Comprehend API in Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, text, analytics

I'm adding this dependency in gradle

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-comprehend:2.6.+'
```

but could not find any method/class to use it.

I want to use this for Text Analytics

I want to use these two classes

```
com.amazonaws.services.comprehend.model.DetectEntitiesRequest
com.amazonaws.services.comprehend.model.DetectEntitiesResult
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some issue with the

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-comprehend:2.6.+'
}
```

use instead

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-comprehend:2.6.22'
}
```

Then you will be able to find the AmazonComprehendClient and other comprehend classes.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following dependency in build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-comprehend:2.6.22'
}
```

You need to use `AmazonComprehendClient` class to invoke the Comprehend API.

Create the `AmazonComprehendClient` as follows:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretAccessKey);

AmazonComprehendClient comprehendClient = new AmazonComprehendClient(credentials);
```

Invoke the `detecEntities`:

```
DetectEntitiesRequest detectEntitiesRequest = new DetectEntitiesRequest()
            .withText(ENGLISH_TEXT)
            .withLanguageCode("en");
DetectEntitiesResult detectEntitiesResult = comprehendClient.detectEntities(detectEntitiesRequest);
```

Comment: I can't import AmazonComprehendClient  in my code, what dependency did you used?

Comment: I updated the answer with dependencies section. Artifacts are downloaded from here: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-android-sdk-comprehend/2.6.22/. Can you resync the dependencies?

Comment: I'm using the same dependency ... tried to resync many time but still Android studio can't find the AmazonComprehendClient class

Comment: I even tried to add the comprehend jar file to my project but no luck

Comment: I'm using the aws rekognition and faceCompare api the same way and they are working fine but somehow  AmazonComprehend api is not including in my project

Comment: We had an issue in 2.6.20 where the maven artifact didn't have the code. We fixed it in 2.6.21. So 2.6.21 and 2.6.22 should have the right jars. Can you cleanup the gradle cache, android studio build cache and any local maven repository? Also can you check if you added the dependency in the right build.grade file (the build.gradle file of the module where you wanted to use Comprehend)?

Comment: I changed  implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-comprehend:2.6.+'  to  implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-comprehend:2.6.22' now its working fine Thanks alot for your help

Comment: Great! Thank you for confirming!